# How to parse xsd using xsd-parser-rs?

Tags: rust

Do you know how to parse xsd file into Rust structs using https://github.com/lumeohq/xsd-parser-rs?

I do not know how to run the program and how to put files there.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't seem to be published on crates.io. Have you tried cloning it locally (or just adding it as a dependency) and running `cargo doc`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but I cannot run it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a basic example that parses a file `sample.xsd` and then prints out the debug representation of the parsed result:

#### `src/main.rs`:

```rust
use anyhow::{format_err, Result};
use std::fs;
use xsd_parser::parser::parse as xsd_parse;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let sample = fs::read_to_string("sample.xsd")?;
    let parsed = xsd_parse(&sample).map_err(|_| format_err!("failed to parse XSD file"))?;
    println!("{:#?}", &parsed);

    Ok(())
}
```

#### `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "xsd-demo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
anyhow = "1"
xsd-parser = { git = "https://github.com/lumeohq/xsd-parser-rs", rev = "7f3d433e4f033b55f057e97c0a30de221dbe3ae1" }
```

#### `sample.xsd`:

I used the sample XSD file from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xml-tools/sample-xsd-file-simple-schema?view=vs-2019).

---

From the project folder, you can invoke rustdoc like `cargo doc -p xsd-parser --no-deps --open` to generate and open the API docs for the `xsd-parser` crate, which is what allowed me to figure out how to use the crate.

Comment: Would really appreciate it if you'll share some code, which actually generates rust struct based on XSD file. Just can't understand how to do it with xsd-parser-rs :-(

Comment: @Alexey have a look at the code for the CLI; it shows how to generate the Rust code: https://github.com/lumeohq/xsd-parser-rs/blob/7096535bba0460ff3af9e077a614676c85ea786b/xsd-parser-cli/src/main.rs#L63-L74. Or maybe just using the CLI directly is what you want.

Comment: Exactly what I need @Brian! Works flawlessly! Thank you 